# v-container width change with user's screen size

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-container and I want to change its size according to user's window size. If they have a large screen, I want v-container to be 1/3 of the page width. If the user has a middle-sized screen, I want v-container to be 1/2 of the page width. Otherwise, I want to use the full width. I know that I need to use display breakpoints but I couldn't manage to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to give windows width relative points you need to use vw. As it stands for Viewport Width. 100 vw is full width of window.

For media queries use max-device-width

```
@media (max-device-width: 736px){ 
 ...
}
```

```css
body,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container{
  height:500px;
  width:33vw;
  background:orange;
}

@media (max-device-width: 1200px) {
  .container{
    width:50vw;
  }
}

@media (max-device-width: 667px) {
  .container{
    width:100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Play with this example and find your answer.